# Postgresql: Why does \d+ table not show default as null

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to Postgres from MySQL.

I've created a table with a column 'col' that has its default as null.

```
CREATE TABLE widgets (id serial primary key, col bigint default null);
CREATE TABLE
test=# \d+ widgets;
                                                Table "public.widgets"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |               Default               | Storage | Stats target | Description 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id     | integer |           | not null | nextval('widgets_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              | 
 col    | bigint  |           |          |                                     | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    "widgets_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

test=#
```

However, in the Default column there is nothing to indicate it's a null field.

Should the default value show as null in the schema output?

I've also tried the same example above, but with `default 99`. Nothing shows in the Default column when typing `\d+`. In that example, I insert a row, `INSERT INTO widgets (id) VALUES (1);` it gets the default value `99`, so I know the default value is being used (at least for the integer value).
Update: the default column did in fact show 99. I had used \d+ with autocomplete and viewed the wrong table.

With `default null`, when I `SELECT * FROM widgets` the column shows up blank.

Does Postgres not explicitly show a value marked as 'null'? If not, how is it possible to differentiate between and empty text field and a field with a null value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When nothing is specified a column's default is always `null`. Apparently the `psql` developers thought, that showing `null` as the default value makes no sense. Maybe because it is the standard behavior or because `null` is not a "value".

Only non-null default values are shown in the `\d` output.

---

> *how is it possible to differentiate between and empty text field and a field with a null value?*

An empty string `''` is something different than a `null` value and you will see the difference in the output:

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLE null_test (c1 text default null, c2 text default '');
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# \d null_test
            Table "public.null_test"
 Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------+------+-----------+----------+----------
 c1     | text |           |          |
 c2     | text |           |          | ''::text
```

Comment: I'd say that you see nothing in the `Default` column for a NULL default value because - er - that's the default default value. So if you don't specify a default value it will be NULL.